# Cloning element and modifying inside a jquery loop executes forever

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to clone an element and then modify its text based on the results found in a json request via jquery. However, the clone is being executed forever inside of the each loop and crashing my browser. I'm not sure why, as I haven't used this jquery feature before, so please forgive my lack of understanding..

Anyway here is the code I have in place

jQuery:

```
function buildFriendStatus() {
     $.getJSON('/members/feed/get-friend-status', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            var clone = $('.w3-container.w3-card-2.w3-white.w3-round.w3-margin').clone();

            clone.find('h4').html(data[i].username);
            clone.find('p').html(data[i].status);
            clone.find('img').attr('src', data[i].images);

            clone.insertAfter('.w3-container.w3-card-2.w3-white.w3-round.w3-margin.user-status');
        }); 
    }).fail(function(response) {
        console.log(response.fail);
    }); 
}

setInterval(function() {
    buildFriendStatus();
}, 1000);
```

and the html element(s)

```
<!-- friends activity feed -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    buildSelfStatus();
    buildFriendStatus();
</script>

<!-- always have this first (sticky) for the user status -->
<div class="w3-container w3-card-2 w3-white w3-round w3-margin user-status">
    <h4></h4>

    <p></p>

    <div class="w3-row-padding" style="margin: 0 -16px;">
        <div class="w3-half">
            <img src="" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;" alt="<?php echo $this->identity() . "'s image"; ?>" class="w3-margin-bottom w3-round w3-border">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- element I am cloning -->
<div class="w3-container w3-card-2 w3-white w3-round w3-margin">
    <h4></h4>

    <p></p>

    <div class="w3-row-padding" style="margin: 0 -16px">
        <div class="w3-half">
            <img src="" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;" alt="<?php echo "Image"; ?>" class="w3-margin-bottom w3-round w3-border">
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="w3-btn w3-theme-d1 w3-margin-bottom">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Like
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="w3-btn w3-theme-d2 w3-margin-bottom">
        <i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Comment
    </button>
</div>
```

Basically what I am doing or trying to do, is clone the existing element and put all the text from the `$.getJSON` request inside. However it is just the same thing over and over again.

A screenshot of the issue - [image]

It keeps inserting that over and over again. What I am trying to do is use clone to clone the element and then modify it with the data returned, although I am probably doing it wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Update

*json string:*

```
{
  "feed": {
    "username": "Timmy",
    "status": ["this is jimmy, test"],
    "images": ["\/images\/profile\/timmy\/status\/boned.jpg"]
  }
}
```

Comment: change **setInterval(function() {** with **setTimeout(function() {**

Comment: I did that but I need it to execute every few seconds in case a new status from another person is posted. From what I read setTimeout only executes once

Comment: Could you post the content of `dada` too? I believe the multi-insertion is tied to this line `.insertAfter('.w3-container.w3-card-2.w3-white.w3-round.w3-margin.user-status')` : the clone will be put after each item matching the selector..

Comment: @gaetanoM setTimeout does prevent it from executing forever but it appends it 3 times, with the last not showing anything. I only want it to show once.

Comment: @Stphane what do you mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.clone()` [documentation says](http://api.jquery.com/clone/):

> Description: Create a deep copy of the set of matched element**S**

This means `clone()` will copy **EVERY** element matching the supplied selector.

What happens is, the selector matches a single element on first round, but once the clone has been added to the DOM, the 2nd call (1sec after) will now match 2 elements (the original + the first clone) and so on.

So use `.last()` to limit matches to a single element.

*Replacing this line*

```
var clone = $('.w3-container.w3-card-2.w3-white.w3-round.w3-margin').clone();
```

*with this:*

```
var clone = $('.w3-container.w3-card-2.w3-white.w3-round.w3-margin').last().clone();
```

*will prevent polynomial growing insertions.*

#### Note:

`jQuery.each()` [documentation says](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

> Arrays and array-like objects with a length property (such as a function's arguments object) are iterated by numeric index, from 0 to length-1. Other objects are iterated via their named properties.

So data manipulation is pretty the same whether it is an array or an object.

That said, if you know you are manipulating an array, prefer built-in method [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) over *jQuery* polyfil.

## Demo

Uses *jQuery.each* approach, *(I have replaced AJAX calls with simple timeout)*

```js
// Cache element (jquery) reference
let $injectAfter = $('.w3-container.w3-card-2.w3-white.w3-round.w3-margin.user-status')
// Stub data - According to your PHP script output
, jsonData = {
    feed1: {
      username: "Timmy",
      status: ["this is jimmy, test"],
      images: ["/images/profile/timmy/status/boned.jpg"]
    },
    feed2: {
      username: "Chuck",
      status: ["Chuck, test"],
      images: ["/images/profile/timmy/status/boned.jpg"]
    }
 }
;

function buildFriendStatus() {
  $.each(jsonData, function(key, item) {
    let clone = $('.w3-container.w3-card-2.w3-white.w3-round.w3-margin').last().clone();
    clone.find('h4').html(item.username);
    // Status is an array
    // Change as you see fit, we only take the first element here.
    clone.find('p').html(item.status[0]);
    // Further clone changes here
    // …
    // Finally, append the node into the DOM
    clone.removeClass('hide-me').insertAfter($injectAfter);
  });
}

// Only meant to enhance demo
countdown(10000);
setInterval(function() {
    buildFriendStatus();
    countdown(null);
}, 10000);


// Helpers
function countdown(x) {
   x && (countdown.v = (x/1000)+1, countdown.cd = countdown.v);
   x === null && (countdown.cd = countdown.v);
   (countdown.cd-1 > 0)  && --countdown.cd;
   document.querySelector('#counter').textContent = `Call to server in ${countdown.cd}s`;
   countdown.cd && (clearTimeout(countdown.t), (countdown.t = setTimeout(countdown, 1000)));
}
```

```css
.user-status .w3-half{border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid black;padding: 3px}
.hide-me{display: none}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="counter"></p>

<div class="w3-container w3-card-2 w3-white w3-round w3-margin user-status">
  <h4></h4>
  <p></p>
  <div class="w3-row-padding">
    <div class="w3-half">
      Block ".user-status"
      <!-- img src="" class="w3-margin-bottom w3-round w3-border" -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="w3-container w3-card-2 w3-white w3-round w3-margin hide-me">
  <h4></h4>
  <p></p>
  <div class="w3-row-padding">
    <div class="w3-half">
      <!-- img src="" class="w3-margin-bottom w3-round w3-border" -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <button type="button" class="w3-btn w3-theme-d1 w3-margin-bottom">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Like
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="w3-btn w3-theme-d2 w3-margin-bottom">
        <i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Comment
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: @user2101411 Check this out, I've spotted two issues and also added a demo.

Comment: but I'm returning a json string from the php side, so would it work

Comment: @user2101411 This is what I suspected (but was not sure since you use `data[i]` to reference items), please post the JSON string at the end of your question and I will adapt the code accordingly if needed.

Comment: added the json string. I thought the i and item were needed for looping through json results (or so all the examples I saw were)

Comment: I was adding all the status to an array in PHP. Is that not right?

Comment: So your json string represent an object which means that jQuery should parse it correctly. I will edit my answer, but first why is the status key an array ?

Comment: I was adding all the status to an array in PHP. Is that not right?

Comment: I thought you had only one status. If there are multiple status an array is okey. How should status be rendered on a single item? Should they be concatenated with spaces?

Comment: well my goal was to retrieve all statuses from friends and then have them show up within those elements. But if I use `setInterval` it just shows all the same one over and over again (I will have more statuses, this is just testing). If I use `setTimeout` though, it lists it once but doesn't keep checking repeatedly if there are more statuses just posted

Comment: Okey but that sounds not so clear to me. What I understand is that a friend is a `feed` and a `feed` has multiple status. So should the loop render one `w3-container` per feed each `feed` having multiple status?

Comment: yes but right now there is only one, this is only testing, I want to get it to work then add more statuses. One small problem though, it is still having the empty elements at the bottom of the list (https://imgur.com/uPPClAb)

Comment: I will update the code later, I got to go right now. Stay tuned.

Comment: @user2101411 I made an heavy lift. The code will now handle your PHP script output. I just arranged the markup a bit. Don't forget to mark it as solved by ticking the answer.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out

Comment: i ran the code snippet and its what I need (except for no images) but I was wondering how to not show the same one more than once

Comment: I'm confused about the `let $injectAfter` part. How would I use the json string being returned by PHP there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167321/discussion-between-stphane-and-user2101411).